# Why does JSON serialization return a partially deserialized object?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, converters

I have this method:

```
public Specification RequestUnit(string jsonString)
{
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SkuModel>(jsonString.Replace("on", "1"));
    return inteService.RequestSpecification(obj);
}
```

And, this is my JSON and is **exactly** what is contained in *jsonString*

```
{
"RequestStatus":"on",
"IsActive":"on",
"Code":"g87",
"Name":"fg8907",
"UnitDescription":"8gf"
}
```

Unfortunately, and for some unknown reason, the *obj* variable is only partially set. All parameters except for *UnitDescription* (which remains null) are successfully deserialized. I am using the Newtonsoft.Json JsonConvert class.

Anybody?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cause of this problem is this:

```
jsonString.Replace("on", "1")
```

`Replace()` method will replace every occurence of "on". So, your actual JSON will be like this:

```
{
    "RequestStatus":"1",
    "IsActive":"1",
    "Code":"g87",
    "Name":"fg8907",
    "UnitDescripti1":"8gf"
}
```

Note `UnitDescripti1` name.

The workaround will be using

```
jsonString.Replace("\"on\"", "\"1\"")
```

But it's better to configure you deserialization process or use custom JsonConverter, as you can get the same issue again.

Comment: Haha, can´t believe I did not see it :) Thanks, it should actually be like this: var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SkuModel>(skuModel.Replace("\"on\"", "\"1\""));

Answer (score 2):

As [@Eldar mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25666978/497356), you could use a custom `JsonConverter` for `bool` values. It's probably a bit safer to do this than to try to replace certain values in the JSON string.

```
public class BooleanOnOffConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(
        JsonWriter writer,
        object value,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue((bool)value ? "on" : "off");
    }

    public override object ReadJson(
        JsonReader reader, 
        Type objectType, 
        object existingValue, 
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return reader.Value.ToString() == "on";
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(bool);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
SkuModel deserialized = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SkuModel>(jsonString, new BooleanOnOffConverter());
```